# Can I Mount ENCFS container from Ubuntu live usb?

Tags: mount, live-usb, encfs

I'm having bootup problems with my Linux Mint installation. I'm using an Ubuntu live usb to back up my stuff. I want to mount my ENCFS container to back up the files, but I can't figure out how to do it from a live disk. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `man encfs` should tell you all you need to know. I think the command is essentially

```
encfs /the/encrypted-dir /the/empty/mountpoint-dir
```

replacing directories with your real ones. If there are any errors I think there's a `-v` option for more info, and check logs, and update your Q if it doesn't work. All the needed info should be in a config file in the encrypted dir + your passphrase.

FYI, `encfs` is probably not installed on a default live iso, so you'll first need the internet, and

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get encfs`

Comment: I found a solution [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186487/can-encfs-container-be-mounted-from-live-disk/186712).